# How many ways of combining 4 fruits, repeting at most 1 twice?

Tags: combinatorics

another simple question -

How many ways do I have of picking 4 fruits among a menu of 8 types of fruits, repeting at most 1 type twice? This is a simple exercise, but I got really stuck at it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many types of fruits are there among the $8$ fruits in the basket?

Comment: It's irrelevant for this problem. You can consider they're all of the same type.

Comment: If they are all identical apples, then how would it be possible to pick $4$ fruits such that at most $2$ are apples? All of them would be apples.

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake while copying the question. check again.

Comment: Ohh sorry, now I got your point. I've edited the question now, it's 8 types of fruits. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Please note that I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can first choose 4 distinct fruits from the 8. This gives us $8\choose4$ possibilities.

To allow for double fruit types, we can choose 3 fruits, then just double any one of them. There are $3{8\choose3}$ possibilities here.

Add them up

$${8\choose4}+3{8\choose3}$$

Edit: I'm sorry but the above is wrong, well incomplete. We still need to include when we have two pairs of fruit. That is choosing 2 fruits and doubling both up.

$${8\choose4}+3{8\choose3}+{8\choose2}=266$$